# How does one escape left/right braces in ANTLR3 header sections?

Tags: c++, c, header-files, antlr3, tree-grammar

I have an ANTLR3 tree grammar with C as the target language. This tree grammar actually generates C++ objects and thus needs to include the header(s) for these classes. I use the `@header` section for this. However, in the output, there is an `extern C {` and `}` block that also encompasses the header section output. This is causing errors because the header has templates, which cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage. I'd like to close that block at the beginning of my header section's output and reopen it at the end. Unfortunately, writing braces inside of the `@header` section breaks the ANTLR3 syntax - braces mark the beginning and end of the `@header` section.

How can I escape these braces?

TLDR:
I need to write left brackets and right brackets into the `@header` section of my ANTLR3 tree grammar. Doing so breaks the syntax for a the `@header` section. How can I escape the left/right braces so that the header section of the generated output can contain left/right brackets?

Editing them in manually after each output is... bothersome.

Comment: Just an idea: #define RBRACE as }, LBRACE as { and use the macros... Don't know if that will work, and it is not pretty.

Comment: I don't know if they'll work, but C and C++ do accept digraphs for braces: `<%` is a `{` and `%>` is a `}`.